# How to assign different apps for mailto handling, depending on the program the link is in?

Tags: google-chrome, outlook, gmail, mailto

I use both gmail (through Chrome) and the Outlook desktop app, both on Windows 10.
Right now chrome is set to handle all mailto links, no matter in which program I click a mailto link.

This is not ideal, as any mailto link I click in outlook is opened in gmail. Therefore I would like to set Outlook to handle all mailto links I click in Outlook, and gmail to handle all mailto links I click in Chrome.

When I try to search for solutions, all I find is people describing how to change the mailto handler for Windows, not how to have different handlers depending on which program the click originated from.

If it is not possible using only Windows settings, solutions that involve potential third party software are also welcome.

Comment: does this article help you? https://linuxhint.com/get-email-links-open-chrome/

Comment: @michal.jakubeczy no, the article just describes how to make all mailto links open in chrome